# Julia Initialized Array / Vector is not zero but random

Tags: arrays, initialization, constants, julia

When I define an Array in Julia:

```
z = Array(Float64, 1)
```

it appears a random value is assigned. Sometimes it is 0.0, but mostly it is something like 3.78692e-316.

Is this  behaviour intended?

And how do I initialize a "constant" vector with 10 values, such as `b = [2.0 2 2 2]`?

Comment: I would add that it is also sometimes `NaN`, and in Julia Studio I've observed even stranger values, e.g. `5.30971e6`. I too am curious as to what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 10):

@waTeim is correct that when allocating an array it is not initialized to 0 or any specific value.

The way to allocate and initialize a new array with a specific value in Julia is with `fill()` so for your `b` you would do:

```
b = fill(2.0, 10)
```

This gives you:

```
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
```

Or if you want a row vector:

```
b = fill(2.0, 1, 10)
```

Which gives you

```
1x10 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: There's also `zeros` and `ones` for initialized arrays with those values.

Comment: How does that work if you have type aliases in play? For example, this: ``const C4SqVal = UInt8;
const C4Board = Matrix{C4SqVal}
`` along with ``const emptySquare = C4SqVal(0)`` along with ``newBoard(height::Integer=6,width::Integer=7) = fill(emptySquare,(height,width))`` does **not** work.

Answer (score 2):

### Array Allocation

It appears that array allocation does not initialize when the element type is [unboxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Boxing) (see below).  This happens at a very low level in the system and is by the way is part of the API when Julia is [embedded](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/embedding/#working-with-arrays) in another program.  At the lowest level in the source code for Julia object allocation is performed by the function [**allocobj**](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/gc.c#L1029).

```
DLLEXPORT void *allocobj(size_t sz)
{
#ifdef MEMDEBUG
    return alloc_big(sz);
#endif
    if (sz > 2048)
        return alloc_big(sz);
    return pool_alloc(&pools[szclass(sz)]);
}
```

The function **alloc_big** is essentially a call to **malloc** which does not initialize the memory it allocates, while **pool_alloc** is a function that acquires memory from set of free lists managed by Julia and likewise also does not initialize.  This makes sense because here is time that would likely be wasted because the program will usually turn around and initialize this to something program specific anyway.

However, there is an exception in the case of arrays, the function [**_new_array_**](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/array.c#L39) contains

```
if (!isunboxed)
   memset(data, 0, tot);
```

The value of this variable is determined from [this function](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/array.c#L19). To be stored unboxed in an array, elements must be leaf, immutable, non-pointer-containing types.

```
static inline int store_unboxed(jl_value_t *el_type)
{
    return jl_is_datatype(el_type) && jl_is_leaf_type(el_type) && jl_is_immutable(el_type) && jl_is_pointerfree((jl_datatype_t*)el_type);
}
```

The primitive types ***Bool***, ***Int64***, ***Float64***, etc are classified immutable as well as leaf (non-abstract) and of course non-pointer and so will be stored unboxed, and therefore not initialized.

```
julia> Float64.mutable
false
```

Further, immutable composite types appears to also trigger this behavior.

```
julia> immutable type Foo bar::Int end

julia> z=Array(Foo,1)
1-element Array{Foo,1}:
 Foo(0)

julia> z=Array(Foo,1)
1-element Array{Foo,1}:
 Foo(-4)

julia> z=Array(Foo,1)
1-element Array{Foo,1}:
 Foo(4432839632)
```

### Const Vector Initialization

Likely you want something like this:

```
julia> const C = [2, 2, 2, 2.0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 2.0
 2.0
 ...
 2.0

julia> D = [ 1 ];

julia> C = D;
ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant C
```

Comment: Wait a minute... How is this C code related to Julia? I remember of a policy in which Julia should never resort to C. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @juliohm It is true that Julia is implemented mostly using Julia, but at the lowest level, it's implemented in C++.  At this level things like parsing, dynamic library loading, garbage collection and object allocation is done.  I've updated the above answer some to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is as follows:

```
julia> zeros(3) 
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

or for ones:

```
julia> ones(3)
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
```

or for some particular value:

```
julia> ones(3)*2
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 2.0
 2.0
 2.0
```

Comment: Or alternatively for the last one `fill(2.0,3)` as mentioned in some of the other answers